# How to save attachments filename into a field?

Tags: 2013, rest, xslt

I am trying to create a URL/ Link with current item attachment filename.

My example

- List name:   MyList
- ItemID :  100
- LinkField:    NULL
- attachments:  abc.csv & abv.doc

I would like create a string like : `MyItem=100&Myattachment=abc.csv`
and save into a field (`LinkField`)

I can use javascript, REST, XSL, or anything to make it work.

Comment: I don't need something like this:  
 <xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
          <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ListId">{D2C70ED5-8551-446D-B0CF-AC4B30387CF0}</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">              <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>          </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:element>

Comment: If you can just display in the aspx page, it might work for me.

Display it as html code:
<a href="http://Mysite/home.aspx?MyItem=100&Myattachment=abc.csv">link</a>....
<a href="http://Mysite/home.aspx?MyItem=100&Myattachment=abv.doc">link</a>....

Comment: In Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone! Finally, I can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just need a column that contains a link to each attachment that that item has.

An easy way is to do it via jquery and then attach it to the list.

Answer taken from here:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74dac191-5a9e-4970-a9f6-a501846f0bef/forum-faq-show-attachments-in-sharepoint-2013-custom-list-view?forum=sharepointgeneral

See code below:

```
(function () {

// Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it output render  

var attachmentsFiledContext = {};

attachmentsFiledContext.Templates = {};

attachmentsFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {

    "Attachments": { "View": AttachmentsFiledTemplate }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(attachmentsFiledContext);

})();


// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function AttachmentsFiledTemplate(ctx) {
var itemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
var listName = ctx.ListTitle;       
return getAttachments(listName, itemId);
   }

//get attachments field properties
function getAttachments(listName,itemId) {

var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var requestUri = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
var str = "";
// execute AJAX request
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            str += "<a href='" + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</a>";
            if (i != data.d.results.length - 1) {
                str += "<br/>";
            }                
        }          
    },
    error: function (err) {
        //alert(err);
    }
});
return str;
```

}

Comment: I have uploaded the js files and create a view for my list.  But I cannot "edit page" it because it is the list view page. I can Edit List.  So how can I put "~site/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/showAttachments.js" into JSLink field?  Do I need to create a blank new page and add the list web parts?

Comment: I created a new page and added the list in the page.  Then, put the "~site/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/showAttachments.js" into JSLink field.
But it return error like this: 
"'$' is undefinedTypeError: Unable to get value of the property '_events': object is null or undefined"

Comment: If I remove "|~site/SiteAssets/showAttachments.js", the page is working fine.

Comment: I would assume that the link you are using is wrong. Is the url for the .js correct?
(Currently don't have the time to test this although I have used it before so it should work somehow)

Comment: The link is fine. Because "~site/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" file is working fine.

Comment: Now, I found the error code:
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined it is near the ajax.
Why "$" is undefined?  How can I need to define $? Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. What was the issue with the $?

Comment: <script type="text\javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
This is the issue.
"\" vs "/"

Comment: Question for #Roland - how can I add the target=_blank within the ,a href= .... ??? need so that the link / file opens in a new window tab . Any suggestions?

Comment: #Bucki You need to edit the str += "<a href='"... line to add the target attribute as a string. simply append it to the right place